# Codeigniter watermarking word wrap

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

I have a website where users can type on an image and mail it. I am using Codeigniter watermark function to put the text on the image. However,the text doesn't appear same as the user typed. The text is word wrapped in the editor, but when you watermark it, the text gets cut. It displays just 1 line of text on the image and cuts what doesn't fit. How can i use word wrap with watermark?

Answer (score 0):

Try It.

$config['wm_text'] =  wordwrap("your wathermark text that is very loooong", 15, "\n");

Comment: you cannot give a fixed number of letters as the font size can change. Moreover, the spacing changes for every font family.

Comment: imagesx() / imagefontwidth() = num_letters_to_wordwrap